# How can I download an html2canvas screenshot as a jpeg instead of a png?

Tags: html2canvas

I've set up a web page that allows you to take a screenshot of a div and save it, using html2canvas to capture the image and FileSaver.js to download the file.

I can’t figure out how to make the image a jpeg instead of a png and control the quality, even though that seems to be something html2canvas can do. How do I control image type?

Here's the working code at the moment, that saves an image of the div as a png.

```
function generateScreenshot() {
  $('#saveimagelink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = document.getElementById("divtocapture");

    html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            window.saveAs(blob, "downloaded.png");
        });
    });

  });
}
```

Thank you!